# How to install SQLite in Windows (when there's no sqlite-shell and sqlite3.exe)?

Tags: windows, sqlite

Most of the tutorial I found online mention sqlite-shell to install sqlite in Windows, but I could not find it in SQLite download page nor through searching online anywhere else.

When I went to the download page, the ones under Windows are only:

**Precompiled Binaries for Windows**

*sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3170000.zip*
(431.40 KiB)        32-bit DLL (x86) for SQLite version 3.17.0.
(sha1: a97cebc176b3daa453189f2c0b7cf2a5a70f9c92)

*sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3170000.zip*
(715.39 KiB)        64-bit DLL (x64) for SQLite version 3.17.0.
(sha1: deba09d3c18bf4cdf9e0c3af7f7e7147d9f4fab9)

*sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3170000.zip*
(1.54 MiB)      A bundle of command-line tools for managing SQLite database files, including the command-line shell program, the sqldiff.exe program, and the sqlite3_analyzer.exe program.
(sha1: 66cff70dc901eb6015a5c425cd7ec527f02628a0)

Help? Total newbie here...

Comment: What's wrong with the first two? Just choose the correct SO version  (32 or 64) and proceed... well, the shell is in the tools, 3rd zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, the SQLite librariy is compiled directly into your application; in this case, you would download the source code (the amalgamation).

To get the SQLite shell (`sqlite3.exe`), download the tools package. It does not need installation; just unpack it (in some appropriate directoy).